# Доступ к аудиозаписям VK в контексте принципов ООП

Tags: c#, ооп, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Имеется сущность Пользователь. У пользователя есть список аудиозаписей. Чтобы получить доступ к аудиозаписям Пользователя, нужно с помощью клиентской авторизации получить токен, и с помощью этого токена обращаться к аудиозаписям. Примерно так:

```
public class User 
{
    public string Token;    

    public void Authorize()
    {
        Token = // какие-то действия по получению токена
    }
}

public class Audio
{
   public string Id;

   public string Name;

   // ....

   // проблема тут
   public static Audio GetSongById(string id, string token)
   { ... }
}
```

Теперь к проблеме. Я не могу получить аудиозапись, зная только её ID: нужен ещё и токен. Но по идее класс `Audio` не должен ничего знать о токене: эта сущность для него посторонняя. Токен относится к `User`. Однако каждый раз приходится передавать этот токен в методы классов, работающих с API (таких, как `Audio.GetSongById`).

Есть ли какая-то возможность сделать так, чтобы мои классы ничего не знали об этом токене? Или придется мириться с этим?

Comment: Нет ли у вас отдельного класса, отвечающего за работу с API ВК?
Аудио сам по себе, а получить его от ВК — отдельная история, задействующая юзера, авторизацию, сеть (вдруг инет отключен?) и пр. Потом, может, вы станете кэшировать аудио на своей CDN, и тогда появится способ получить аудио еще и оттуда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем так.

Давайте рассмотрим произвольную аудиозапись, не обязательно из списка аудиозаписей пользователя. Один и тот же аудиофайл может, по идее, быть доступен разным пользователям. Если пользователь `A` даст доступ пользователю `B`, то вы сможете получить доступ к аудиофайлу с токеном пользователя `B` (у вас может и не быть токена пользователя `A`). То, что список *собственных* аудиозаписей пользователю (скорее всего) доступен, свойство лишь собственных аудиозаписей, выполняется не всех аудиофайлов.

Поэтому кроме класса `Audio` при любом доступе вам нужен токен доступа. Правильнее было бы назвать функцию `GetSongByIdFor(string id, User user)`.

Или вам нужно завести класс `UsersAudio`, который будет внутри себя знать своего пользователя, и уж по одному лишь `id` давать `Audio`.

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть класс VkRequester. В нем и хранится token. И в общем виде он просто предоставляет возможность слать post-запросы в одну строчку. В нем обрабатываются http исключения и ошибки, на выход все его методы возвращают строку, которую я позже десериализую в то что нужно.